# boost ublas: rotate 2d vector

Tags: c++, boost, ublas

Erm. I hope I am seriously overlooking something.
I want to rotate a 2d vector (kartesian) v by a certain angle phi.

I can't find a function that generates the appropriate matrix
or just performs that function.

I know how to do this by hand. I am looking for a ublas utility "something" 
that does this for me.

Answer (score 2):

BLAS == Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines, emphasis on the ***basic***. The BLAS functions are extremely general, they don't have anything nearly as specific as 2D vector rotations. 
Just do it manually: make your own function that builds a

```
[cos phi,-sin phi
 sin phi, cos phi]
```

matrix and multiplies it with your vector.

Comment: actually, functions to generate and apply rotations are in blas, to use with givens rotations